# TCP sockets not closing when fetching from S3 using boto

Tags: python, sockets, amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-s3

How do you cleanup/close/reuse sockets made using `boto` to connect to an S3 bucket?

[This discussion](https://code.google.com/p/boto/issues/detail?id=412) from 2010 says it is a problem with `httplib.HTTPSConnection` instead of `boto`. In my code, I use `key.close(fast=True)` for all the keys I get from `boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.list()`. Every time I use a key to reference the file, boto opens an unique socket, and after a while I will get `[Errno 24]: Too many open files`.

When I run `lsof | grep python` I get a variety of these:

```
python    10573 ec2-user  399u     IPv4  59221       0t0    TCP ip-10-0-0-113.ec2.internal:59293->s3-1-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
python    10573 ec2-user   72u     IPv4  60910       0t0    TCP ip-10-0-0-113.ec2.internal:37952->s3-1-w.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
python    10573 ec2-user   91u     sock    0,6       0t0  61105 can't identify protocol
```

These are connection types (IPv4 socket, socket), TCP nodes, and the name (the final column) is the localhost:port->TCP remote address (state of TCP/TPI).

`ulimit -a` says the open files maximum is 1024, and an option is simply to raise the maximum. However, I want to make sure I'm closing the files I ought to be.

I think making and reusing 1 socket is smarter, is that possible with boto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was leaking file descriptors :(

Boto keys are iterable, so you should stream data from it, using just the original boto-made-socket (ie, ignoring it and getting boto to do all the work for you) by:

```
for data in key: 
   # etc
```